# kiali showing unkown traffic via sending through ambassador

Tags: istio, amazon-eks, ambassador, kiali

I have installed service mesh(Istio) and working with Ambassador to route traffic to our application. Whenever I am sending traffic through Istio Ingress its working fine and working with the ambassador but when sending through Ambassador, It is showing unknown, You can see on the attached image, could be related to the fact that the ambassador does not use an Istio sidecar.

[image]

Used code to deploy Ambassador service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ambassador
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  ports:
    - name: ambassador-http
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    service: ambassador
---
```

Is there anything to I can add here to make it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible and here is detailed guide for this from Abmassador [documentation](https://www.getambassador.io/user-guide/with-istio/):

---

### Getting Ambassador Working With Istio

Getting Ambassador working with Istio is straightforward. In this example, we'll use the  `bookinfo`  sample application from Istio.

1. Install Istio on Kubernetes, following  [the default instructions](https://istio.io/docs/setup/kubernetes/install/kubernetes/)  (without using mutual TLS auth between sidecars)
2. Next, install the Bookinfo sample application, following the  [instructions](https://istio.io/docs/examples/bookinfo/#if-you-are-running-on-kubernetes).
3. Verify that the sample application is working as expected.

By default, the Bookinfo application uses the Istio ingress. To use Ambassador, we need to:

1. Install Ambassador.

First you will need to deploy the Ambassador ambassador-admin service to your cluster:

It's simplest to use the YAML files we have online for this (though of course you can download them and use them locally if you prefer!).

First, you need to check if Kubernetes has RBAC enabled:

```sh
kubectl cluster-info dump --namespace kube-system | grep authorization-mode
```

If you see something like  `--authorization-mode=Node,RBAC`  in the output, then RBAC is enabled.

If RBAC is enabled, you'll need to use:

```sh
kubectl apply -f https://getambassador.io/yaml/ambassador/ambassador-rbac.yaml
```

Without RBAC, you can use:

```sh
kubectl apply -f https://getambassador.io/yaml/ambassador/ambassador-no-rbac.yaml
```

(Note that if you are planning to use mutual TLS for communication between Ambassador and Istio/services in the future, then the order in which you deploy the ambassador-admin service and the ambassador LoadBalancer service below may need to be swapped)

Next you will deploy an ambassador service that acts as a point of ingress into the cluster via the LoadBalancer type. Create the following YAML and put it in a file called  `ambassador-service.yaml`.

```
---
apiVersion: getambassador.io/v1
kind: Mapping
metadata: 
  name: httpbin
spec:     
  prefix: /httpbin/
  service: httpbin.org
  host_rewrite: httpbin.org
```

Then, apply it to the Kubernetes with  `kubectl`:

```sh
kubectl apply -f ambassador-service.yaml
```

The YAML above does several things:

- It creates a Kubernetes service for Ambassador, of type  `LoadBalancer`. Note that if you're not deploying in an environment where  `LoadBalancer`  is a supported type (i.e. MiniKube), you'll need to change this to a different type of service, e.g.,  `NodePort`.
- It creates a test route that will route traffic from  `/httpbin/`  to the public  `httpbin.org`  HTTP Request and Response service (which provides useful endpoint that can be used for diagnostic purposes). In Ambassador, Kubernetes annotations (as shown above) are used for configuration. More commonly, you'll want to configure routes as part of your service deployment process, as shown in  [this more advanced example](https://www.datawire.io/faster/canary-workflow/).

You can see if the two Ambassador services are running correctly (and also obtain the LoadBalancer IP address when this is assigned after a few minutes) by executing the following commands:

```sh
$ kubectl get services
NAME               TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)          AGE
ambassador         LoadBalancer   10.63.247.1     35.224.41.XX     8080:32171/TCP     11m
ambassador-admin   NodePort       10.63.250.17    <none>           8877:32107/TCP   12m
details            ClusterIP      10.63.241.224   <none>           9080/TCP         16m
kubernetes         ClusterIP      10.63.240.1     <none>           443/TCP          24m
productpage        ClusterIP      10.63.248.184   <none>           9080/TCP         16m
ratings            ClusterIP      10.63.255.72    <none>           9080/TCP         16m
reviews            ClusterIP      10.63.252.192   <none>           9080/TCP         16m

$ kubectl get pods
NAME                             READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
ambassador-2680035017-092rk      2/2       Running   0          13m
ambassador-2680035017-9mr97      2/2       Running   0          13m
ambassador-2680035017-thcpr      2/2       Running   0          13m
details-v1-3842766915-3bjwx      2/2       Running   0          17m
productpage-v1-449428215-dwf44   2/2       Running   0          16m
ratings-v1-555398331-80zts       2/2       Running   0          17m
reviews-v1-217127373-s3d91       2/2       Running   0          17m
reviews-v2-2104781143-2nxqf      2/2       Running   0          16m
reviews-v3-3240307257-xl1l6      2/2       Running   0          16m
```

Above we see that external IP assigned to our LoadBalancer is 35.224.41.XX (XX is used to mask the actual value), and that all ambassador pods are running (Ambassador relies on Kubernetes to provide high availability, and so there should be two small pods running on each node within the cluster).

You can test if Ambassador has been installed correctly by using the test route to  `httpbin.org`  to get the external cluster  [Origin IP](https://httpbin.org/ip)  from which the request was made:

```sh
$ curl 35.224.41.XX/httpbin/ip
{
  "origin": "35.192.109.XX"
}
```

If you're seeing a similar response, then everything is working great!

(Bonus: If you want to use a little bit of awk magic to export the LoadBalancer IP to a variable AMBASSADOR_IP, then you can type `export AMBASSADOR_IP=$(kubectl get services ambassador | tail -1 | awk '{ print $4 }')`and use`curl $AMBASSADOR_IP/httpbin/ip`

2. Now you are going to modify the bookinfo demo  `bookinfo.yaml`  manifest to include the necessary Ambassador annotations. See below.

```
---
apiVersion: getambassador.io/v1
kind: Mapping
metadata: 
  name: productpage
spec:     
  prefix: /productpage/
  rewrite: /productpage
  service: productpage:9080
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: productpage
  labels:
    app: productpage
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 9080
    name: http
  selector:
    app: productpage
```

The annotation above implements an Ambassador mapping from the '/productpage/' URI to the Kubernetes productpage service running on port 9080 ('productpage:9080'). The 'prefix' mapping URI is taken from the context of the root of your Ambassador service that is acting as the ingress point (exposed externally via port 80 because it is a LoadBalancer) e.g. '35.224.41.XX/productpage/'.

You can now apply this manifest from the root of the Istio GitHub repo on your local file system (taking care to wrap the apply with istioctl kube-inject):

```sh
kubectl apply -f <(istioctl kube-inject -f samples/bookinfo/kube/bookinfo.yaml)
```

3. Optionally, delete the Ingress controller from the  `bookinfo.yaml`  manifest by typing  `kubectl delete ingress gateway`.
4. Test Ambassador by going to the IP of the Ambassador LoadBalancer you configured above e.g.  `35.192.109.XX/productpage/`. You can see the actual IP address again for Ambassador by typing  `kubectl get services ambassador`.

---

Also according to [documentation](https://www.getambassador.io/user-guide/with-istio/#automatic-sidecar-injection) there is no need for Ambassador pods to be injected.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have already configured all these things. That's why I have mentioned it in the attached image. I have taken this from kiali dashboard. That output I have shared of the bookinfo application. I have deployed my own application and its also working fine.
But I want short out this **unknown** thing.
I am using the AWS EKS cluster.

**Putting note about ambassador:**
Ambassador should not have the Istio sidecar for two reasons. First, it cannot since running the two separate Envoy instances will result in a conflict over their shared memory segment. The second is Ambassador should not be in your mesh anyway. The mesh is great for handling traffic routing from service to service, but since Ambassador is your ingress point, it should be solely in charge of deciding which service to route to and how to do it. Having both Ambassador and Istio try to set routing rules would be a headache and wouldn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

All the traffic coming from a source that is not part of the service mesh is going to be shown as `unknown`.

See what kiali says about the unknowns:
https://kiali.io/faq/graph/#many-unknown

Comment: The link moved to here: https://kiali.io/documentation/latest/faq/#many-unknown

Comment: and here again. https://kiali.io/docs/faq/graph/